# Force image to download

Tags: html

**Problem:** Is there a way to download an image of a website that is not using HTML5?

I currently have the following:

```
<img src="images/#imgicon#" alt="#Name#" class="float-left"/ ></td><td  class="e"><a href="\Logos\#Name#" download="#Name#">#Name#</a>
```

Is there a easy approach to download the image rather then open the image in the browser?

Comment: So it is not HTML5. The question remains: What version of HTML does your website use?

Comment: A `download` attribute on a link should download the image.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: 
This is the html type. XHTML 1.0. It is a old site I am working on

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I have tried that approach and it wont work based on the version html the site is on.

Comment: I think it is going to be difficult. Can you use PHP on that website?

Comment: @RobertoFlores, so use HTML5. Just change the doctype.